# how to create Tagpicker like SitePicker in aikau(1.0.100)?

Tags: aikau

How to create TagPicker like SitePicker in aikau(1.0.100)?we need to show Tags popup when user clicks Tags button in the Form dialog.

Comment: In which OOB page, you're seeing the Site Picker?

Comment: yes.see this example[https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2014/10/10/re-using-and-customizing-aikau-pickers/].If you these examples when user clicks Recent sites , Favourite sites then only respective sites are coming.But in case of Tag picker when the pop up comes  i.e page loads in the leftside, need to display all  tags stored in the repository.so two vertical menus(display  tags,added tags) should come.